# Use ROS 32 bit and 64 bit parallel

Tags: ubuntu, boost, 32bit-64bit, ros

EDIT1: Ok I am have now installed a Ubuntu 14 in 32 bit to compile my 32bit ROS node. The operating system is ubuntu 14 64 bit and I installed there chroot so that I can start my 32bit node which works fine. Is it now possible to run my node with chroot and all the other nodes are running on the normal 64bit system?!

---

I have the following problem. I must integrate a new ROS node into a existing ROS environment running on a Ubuntu 14.04 64Bit with ROS Indigo. I have to build my ROS node in 32Bit because I have to use a shared library which only exists in 32bit.

1)  First I tried to work with my Ubuntu 16.04 workstation and I installed ROS Kinetic in 64 bit and builded it manually in 32 bit for the 32 bit node. That works fine and I was able to compile my own node. Then I tried to install Indigo on the Ubuntu 16.04 but it fails because Indigo doesn’t support 16.04. So compiled Indigo by myself but it fails with the following error message:

```
<== Failed to process package 'rviz': 
Command '['/home/test/Downloads/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 
'make', '-j2', '-l2']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

2)  Second I tried to install a Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and ROS Indigo which works fine but when I tried to compile the ROS framework in 32 bit it fails because the old libboost version 1.55 doesn’t support multiarch.

Due to other facts I am not able to install a 32Bit Ubuntu on my workstation. So my question is if somebody knows problem 1 or can give me a advise what is the right way?!

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

First of All, You can't Install ROS Indigo On ubuntu 16.04 because the official release of Indigo Is Meant for ubuntu 14.04 (there are ways to install Indigo On 16.04 But Not Recommended and unstable)

And I Don't Think You Need ROS 32Bit To Compile Your Code(I Never Had This Problem On Non-ARM Archs).

If You Can Compile It On Kinetic and communicate With ROS Indigo Over Network You Can Make It Work (Probably!)